# Swift OpenGL ES 1.0

Tags: ios, swift, opengl-es

I want to render some points in opengl es 1.0. I have the following code but i it renders different things than it should. I think it is memory garbage or something simmilar.

I figured out that maybe the problem is in the glVertexAttribPointer function's parameters, but i don't know what should i put as parameter to get it working... Please help if you can. I am trying for more than two weeks already and i really don't have more ideas... :/

```
    //
//  GLPointCloudView.swift


import Foundation
import UIKit
import QuartzCore
import OpenGLES
import GLKit

class GLPointCloudView: UIView{


    let pinchGesture : UIPinchGestureRecognizer = UIPinchGestureRecognizer();
    let panGesture : UIPanGestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer();
    let restClient = RestClient();
    var Vertices : [Point] = [];
    /*   override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    glClearColor(0.1, 0.9, 1, 1.0)
    glClear(GLbitfield(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT))
    }*/
    var eaglLayer: CAEAGLLayer!
    var context: EAGLContext!
    var colorRenderBuffer: GLuint = GLuint()
    var positionSlot: GLuint = GLuint()
    var colorSlot: GLuint = GLuint()
    var indexBuffer: GLuint = GLuint()
    var colorBuffer: GLuint = GLuint()

    var vertexBuffer: GLuint = GLuint()
    var VAO:GLuint = GLuint()

    var xPrev : Float?;
    var yPrev : Float?;
    var xAngle : Float = 0;
    var yAngle : Float = 0;
    var TOUCH_ROT_FACTOR = Float(180.0 / 320);
    let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults();
    var controller : UIViewController?;
    let globalData = GlobalDataFunctions();

    /* Class Methods
    ------------------------------------------*/

    override class func layerClass() -> AnyClass {
        // In order for our view to display OpenGL content, we need to set it's
        //   default layer to be a CAEAGLayer
        return CAEAGLLayer.self
    }
    func setInstance(sender: UIViewController){
        self.controller = sender;
        if(globalData.isConnectedToNetwork(true)){
            getPly();
        }else{
            AlertDialogs.showNoInternetAlert(self.controller!);
        }

    }

    /* Lifecycle
    ------------------------------------------*/

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.userInteractionEnabled = true;
        self.multipleTouchEnabled = true;

        self.setupLayer()
        self.setupContext()
      //  self.compileShaders()

        self.setGestureListeners();
        if(globalData.isConnectedToNetwork(true)){
            getPly();
        }
           }

    func getPly(){
      //  restClient.getPly(userDefaults.objectForKey("username") as String, password: userDefaults.objectForKey("password") as String, ply: "19", //myComletionHandler: completionHandler)
            var data = "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n"
            data += "0 -1 10 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 \n";
            data  +=  "0 0 10 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 \n";
            data  +=  "0 2 10 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 \n";
            data  +=  "0 4 10 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 \n";
            data  +=  "0 10 10 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 \n";
            data  +=  "0 -1 10 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 ";

            completionHandler(data);
        }
    func completionHandler(data:String){

        var error: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSError?> = nil
       // NSLog("visszajött: "+data);
              //minta adat 0.84625 -0.414991 2.53928 -0.861408 -0.186617 -0.472387 83 25 4 0.0020861
        let dataArray = data.componentsSeparatedByString("\n");
        println(dataArray.count);
        for(var i = 14; i < dataArray.count; i++ ){
           // println("data:"+dataArray[i]);
            let row = dataArray[i].componentsSeparatedByString(" ");
             if(dataArray[i] != ""){
            //    println("row:"+row[i].debugDescription);

            let x = (row[0].floatValue);
            let y = (row[1].floatValue);
            let z = (row[2].floatValue);
            let nx = (row[3].floatValue);
            let ny = (row[4].floatValue);
            let nz = (row[5].floatValue);
            let r = (row[6].floatValue) / 255;
            let g = (row[7].floatValue) / 255;
            let b = (row[8].floatValue) / 255;
            let a = Float(0.0)//(row[9].floatValue);
                Vertices.append(Point(position: [x,y,z], color: [r,g,b,a]));
               // Vertices.append(Point(position: (x, y, z) , color: (r,g, b, a)));
               // Vertices.append(Vertex(x:x,y:y,z:z,r:r,g:g,b:b,a:a));
            }
        }


        self.setupRenderBuffer()
        self.setupFrameBuffer()
        self.setupVBOs()
        //self.render();


    }

    func pinchHandler(sender:UIPinchGestureRecognizer){
        glMatrixMode(GLenum(GL_PROJECTION));

        glScalef(Float(sender.scale),Float(sender.scale),Float(sender.scale));
         sender.scale = 1;
              self.render();
    }
    func panHandler(sender:UIPanGestureRecognizer){
        // println("pan");
        // if(sender.loca)
        glMatrixMode(GLenum(GL_PROJECTION));

        if(sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began){
            var xV = sender.locationOfTouch(0, inView:self).x;
            var yV = sender.locationOfTouch(0, inView:self).y;

            xPrev = Float(xV);
            yPrev = Float(yV);
        }
        if(sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Changed){
            var xV = Float(sender.locationOfTouch(0, inView:self).x);
            var yV = Float(sender.locationOfTouch(0, inView:self).y);

            var dx = xV - xPrev!;
            var dy = yV - yPrev!;

            //var x = -sender.locationOfTouch(0, inView: self).x;
            // var y = -sender.locationOfTouch(0, inView: self).y;
            var angle = -atan2f( Float(dx), Float(dy) ) * Float(180.0) / Float(M_PI);
            xAngle =  (Float(dx) * Float(TOUCH_ROT_FACTOR));
            yAngle =  (Float(dy) * Float(TOUCH_ROT_FACTOR));
         //   println("angle: \(angle), xV: \(dx), yV: \(dy)");

            //glRotatef(angle, Float(dx), Float(dy), 0);
            glRotatef(xAngle,1,0,0);
            glRotatef(yAngle,0,1,0);
           // println("xAngle: \(xAngle), xV: \(dx), yV: \(dy)");

           // println("yAngle: \(yAngle), xV: \(dx), yV: \(dy)");

            xPrev = Float(xV);
            yPrev = Float(yV);

            self.render();
        }
    }

    func setGestureListeners(){

        pinchGesture.addTarget(self, action: "pinchHandler:");
        panGesture.addTarget(self, action: "panHandler:");
        self.addGestureRecognizer(pinchGesture);
        self.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture);

    }



    /* Instance Methods
    ------------------------------------------*/

    func setupLayer() {
        // CALayer's are, by default, non-opaque, which is 'bad for performance with OpenGL',
        //   so let's set our CAEAGLLayer layer to be opaque.
        self.eaglLayer  = self.layer as CAEAGLLayer
        self.eaglLayer.opaque = true
    }

    func setupContext() {
        // Just like with CoreGraphics, in order to do much with OpenGL, we need a context.
        //   Here we create a new context with the version of the rendering API we want and
        //   tells OpenGL that when we draw, we want to do so within this context.
        var api: EAGLRenderingAPI = EAGLRenderingAPI.OpenGLES1
        self.context = EAGLContext(API: api)

        if ((self.context?) == nil) {
            println("Failed to initialize OpenGLES 2.0 context!")
            exit(1)
        }

        if (!EAGLContext.setCurrentContext(self.context)) {
            println("Failed to set current OpenGL context!")
            exit(1)
        }
    }

    func setupRenderBuffer() {
        glGenRenderbuffers(1, &self.colorRenderBuffer)
        glBindRenderbuffer(GLenum(GL_RENDERBUFFER), self.colorRenderBuffer)
        self.context.renderbufferStorage(Int(GL_RENDERBUFFER), fromDrawable:self.eaglLayer)
    }

    func setupFrameBuffer() {
        var frameBuffer: GLuint = GLuint()
        glGenFramebuffers(1, &frameBuffer)
        glBindFramebuffer(GLenum(GL_FRAMEBUFFER), frameBuffer)
        glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GLenum(GL_FRAMEBUFFER), GLenum(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0), GLenum(GL_RENDERBUFFER), self.colorRenderBuffer)
    }

    // Setup Vertex Buffer Objects
    func setupVBOs() {

      //  glGenVertexArraysOES(1, &VAO);
      //  glBindVertexArrayOES(VAO);

        glGenBuffers(1, &vertexBuffer)
        glBindBuffer(GLenum(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER), vertexBuffer)
        glBufferData(GLenum(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER), sizeof(Point), Vertices,GLenum(GL_STATIC_DRAW))

      /* glGenBuffers(1, &colorBuffer)
        glBindBuffer( GLenum(GL_COLOR_ARRAY), colorBuffer)
        glBufferData(GLenum(GL_COLOR_ARRAY), Vertices.size(), Vertices,GLenum(GL_STATIC_DRAW))
*/

        //let positionSlotFirstComponent = UnsafePointer<Int>(bitPattern: 0)
       // glEnableVertexAttribArray(positionSlot)
        let p = (Vertices[0].position);
        let posSlot = positionSlot;
        let size = GLsizei(sizeof(Point));
        glVertexAttribPointer(positionSlot, 3, GLenum(GL_FLOAT), GLboolean(GL_FALSE), GLsizei(sizeof(Point)),p)
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(positionSlot)

        //let colorSlotFirstComponent = UnsafePointer<Int>(bitPattern: sizeof(Float) * 3)
        let c = (Vertices[0].color);

        glVertexAttribPointer(colorSlot, 4, GLenum(GL_FLOAT), GLboolean(GL_FALSE), GLsizei(sizeof(Point)), c)
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(colorSlot)

          glBindBuffer(GLenum(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER), 0)
       // glBindVertexArrayOES(0)

       //  glDisableClientState(GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY));
        glFrontFace(GLenum(GL_CW));
         glViewport(0, 0, GLint(self.frame.size.width), GLint(self.frame.size.height));
       // glTranslatef(0,0,10);
        glEnableClientState(GLenum(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY));
        glEnableClientState(GLenum(GL_COLOR_ARRAY));

        glVertexPointer(3, GLenum(GL_FLOAT), 0, (&vertexBuffer));
        glColorPointer(4, GLenum(GL_FLOAT), 0, (&colorRenderBuffer));

        glPointSize(10.0)
        //glFrontFace(GLenum(GL_CW));


        self.render()

    }

    func render() {
        //  println("lefut");

          glMatrixMode(GLenum(GL_MODELVIEW));
         // glLoadIdentity();
        // glTranslatef(0, 0, 30);
        // glRotatef(x_angle_, 0, 1, 0);
        // glRotatef(y_angle_, 1, 0, 0);

        glClearColor(1, 1, 1,  0.5);
        glClear(GLenum(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT) | GLenum(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT));


         glDrawArrays(GLenum(GL_POINTS), 0, GLsizei((Vertices.size())));
      //  glBindVertexArray(0);
        self.context.presentRenderbuffer(Int(GL_RENDERBUFFER))


    }

}




//helper extensions to pass arguments to GL land

extension String {
    var floatValue: Float {
        return (self as NSString).floatValue
    }

}



extension Array {
    func size () -> Int {
        return self.count * sizeofValue(self[0])
    }
}

extension Int32 {
    func __conversion() -> GLenum {
        return GLuint(UInt(self))
    }
}


extension Int {
    func __conversion() -> Int32 {
        return Int32(self)
    }

    func __conversion() -> GLubyte {
        return GLubyte(self)
    }

}
```